# Regex to ignore strings with with a certain character in

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to have my regex match sections of a string where theres a "( random values )" except if it find a @ inside that random values it should ignore that section.

For example, I have this string

```
string storeProcDefinition = @"TTTTT.TTTTTTTT (@pname nvarchar, @pdec decimal(18,5) = null, @pnum numeric(18, 10), @pint int = null) AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT TTT"
```

So I want to go and find all the sections that match the "( anything )" in this section like

```
(18,5)
(18, 10)
```

and not the

```
(@pname nvarchar, @pdec decimal(18,5)`
```

My idea was to check for the @ sign in the string or to start over when a new ( is found
But Regex doesn't have an option saying NOT containing a char afik.

I have something like this

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(storeProcDefinition, @"\(^(?!\@)(.*?)\)" );
```

which matches nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\([^@]*?\)
```

should work. [See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/tT1uM6/3)

Explanation:

```
\( // match a literal "("
[^@]*? // match any text except "@"...
\) //...up to the next ")" character
```

Note that this doesn't support nested braces like `foo(bar())`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I started with something close to that and then went in the wrong direction

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I don't think it matters. Both patterns mess up if the input contains nested braces, they just do it differently... (P.s.: Demo updated to illustrate how it deals with nested braces)